# Element requires two clicks to run function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem with an element on a webpage I'm creating where the function that is supposed to run on click is only running after it was clicked once. So the first click does nothing at all while all other clicks work as expected. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="#0" class="packservice" id="rent">Rentals</a>
</div>
<div id="myDIV">
<div class="divinfo">
<div class="servicestxt">
  <h2> Rentals </h2>
<hr>
<br>
  <p>Rent professional beverage serving equpment for your next event. This is our self serve option.</p><br>
  <a href="#0" id="renBut"> Add to Quote </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDIV {
  display: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 2.5% 71.5% 1.5% 1%;
  background-color: white;
}
a.packservice {
  padding: 1% 97% 1% 1%;
  background: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .25%;
  display: block;
}
#packhead {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.divinfo {
 width: 250%;
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left: 50%;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var renBut = document.getElementById("renBut");
var rent = document.getElementById("rent");

function rentalStore() {
if (renBut.innerHTML=="Add to Quote"){
sessionStorage.setItem("rental", true);
renBut.innerHTML = "Remove from Quote"
} else {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("rental");
    renBut.innerHTML = "Add to Quote";
   }
}

//Create function to hide rentals information div
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function clickDom() {
// Create event to listen for click and call corresponding function
console.log("Entering clickDom() function");
   if (rent.addEventListener) {
    rent.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
  }
}  
function buttonEl() {
if (renBut.addEventListener) {
    renBut.addEventListener("click", rentalStore, false);
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  //call init() on page load
   console.log("> Adding TC39 Event Listener...");
   window.addEventListener ("load", buttonEl, false);
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
   console.log("> Adding TC39 Event Listener...");
   window.addEventListener ("load", clickDom, false);
}
```

I also uploaded it to a codepen here: https://codepen.io/seanbarker182/pen/maexPd

There's two things that the javascript does here, the first is just simply unhiding or hiding the div on click so it requires the user to first click 'Rentals' which displays the area that I'm having issues with which is the 'Add to Quote' button. You'll notice that the first click does nothing at all while the second or any proceeding click acts as expected.

Does anyone know why it's requiring that first click to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is fairly simple, and thanks for adding a codepen!

In your HTML you have the following:

```
<a href="#0" id="renBut"> Add to Quote </a>
```

However, in your JS you have:

```
if (renBut.innerHTML=="Add to Quote"){
```

At runtime `renBut.innerHTML` will evaluate to `" Add to Quote "`, notice the extra spaces on either end. The fix can be applied in two ways:

**Remove HTML Spaces**

```
<a href="#0" id="renBut">Add to Quote</a>
```

**Make JavaScript white-space independent**

```
if (renBut.innerHTML.trim()=="Add to Quote"){
```

Which way you do it is just personal preference but personally I would opt for both to ensure consistency and future proofing.

Comment: Oh wow. That's an embarrassing mistake. Thanks for your help!